# change themes.css in magento2

Tags: magento2, css

I am new in magento2.

I have done some changes in a css file and have change the file https://agoshop.at/pub/static/frontend/smart_media/smart_media1/de_DE/css/themes.css on the ftp server.
Here my changes:

```
Code:

.cathead a.level-top {
  background-color: #75dbfa;
  margin-top: 3px !important;
  color: #000 !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  font-family: "Open Sans" !important;
  line-height: 22px !important;
  padding-top: 8px !important;
  padding-bottom: 14px !important;
}
```

But when I open my website agoshop.at I the css will not change.
So I hope someone can help me there how I can do the changes in a css file.
kindly regards for any answer.

Comment: Please do never change any file in the pub directory, this is a folder where magento generates the assets which are needed for the public. Look at the theme self for that file (app/design/... ) or maybe it is generated by settings from backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the following files:

app/design/frontend/smart_media/smart_media1/web/css\themes.less

and

app/design/frontend/smart_media/smart_media1/web/css/themes.css__

After that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment.

I could find a similar file themes.less in app/design/frontend/smart_media/smart_media1/web/css

I have done the same changes and upload the new less file via ftp but there are still no changes.

Where can I find it in the backend?

Hope someone can still help me there.
kindly regards